# Find all functions satisfying $f'= \frac {1}{f}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Find all functions satisfying $f'= \frac {1}{f}$.

**My attempt:** $f'= \frac {df}{dx} = \frac {1}{f} \implies f df =dx \to \int f df = \int dx \to (***)f^2/2 = x+ C$.

I guess there is a mistake in 3 stars because $f$ can be $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ so it is not necessarily $f^2$. What should I do

Comment: I mean derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$

Comment: You have got the right answer: $(f^{2})'=2$ so $f^{2}=2x+C$.

Comment: There is no way $f(x)$ can be $\sin x$ or $\cos x$.

Comment: so you say $f= \sqrt {2x+C}$ however $(\sqrt {2x})'=\sqrt 2 . (\sqrt x)'=\sqrt 2 \frac {1}{2\sqrt x}$ which is true

Comment: why you immediately said that there is no way? @geetha290krm

Comment: What makes you think that the derivative of $\sin x$, which is $\cos x$, is $\frac 1 {\sin x}$?

Comment: @FuatRay If you substitute $f= \sin x$ in the differential equation, you get $\cos x = \frac{1}{\sin x}$, which does not hold for all $x$, only for some selected values of $x$

Comment: Of course, I know derivative of sinx is cosine but I was a little bit confused. But, I am okay now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial reasoning is correct, the solutions of the differential equation are given implicitly by the relation $\frac 12 f^2 = x + C$. There are no other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As Pierre pointed out, your initial reasoning is correct, the solutions of the differential equation are given implicitly by the relation

$\dfrac12f^2=x+C\;.$

There are no other solutions.

Since $\,f^2(x)=2(x+C)\,,\,$ all the solutions are :

$f(x)=\sqrt{2(x+C_1)}:(-C_1,+\infty)\to\Bbb R\qquad$ and

$f(x)=-\sqrt{2(x+C_2)}:(-C_2,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$

where $\,C_1\,$ and $\,C_2\,$ are any two real numbers.